# how to roll back or prevent all executions in Dataform when assertions take place?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dataform, google-workflows

i'm new to Dataform. Does any mechanism i can use to roll back all execution actions or prevent the executions in Workflows or Dataform if Dataform job fails at a point or assertions occurred?

I have configured assertions in sqlx files and also using Workflows to compile and execute jobs.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

After investigating, what I did is writing an assertion type sqlx as an upstream dependency that checks the source data and then make the downstream table depend on that assertion (by adding the name of the assertion sqlx file in the dependencies array in config ). This way your table does not build if your upstream dependency fails.

Comment: Yup this is the way.

Comment: This is the only way works for me the moment. Nothing else i can think of.